# What’s the significance of this extra scope

Tags: production, film-techniques, it-comes-at-night

In “It Comes At Night” (2017), Travis faces hallucinations throughout the movie. Whenever this happens, this second scope kicks in.

[image: second scope]

This second scope also appears in the pre-climax scene, where Paul’s family banishes Kim.